# Using Carrierwave access the image url in the controller wihtout the dot syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I have the image field name stored as a variable. How can I access the uploaded image url within the controller without using the dot syntax? I need to be able to access it dynamically.

I have tried the following way, but it prints out the filename as string not the full URL, however when I access the same within the view file, I am able to access an object with the property `url`;

```
@image_name = 'attachment';
@user = User.find(1)
puts @user[@image_name]
```

As per the documentation from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave we are able to access the URL by the following ways:

```
u.avatar.url # => '/url/to/file.png'
u.avatar.current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
u.avatar_identifier # => 'file.png'
```

Comment: try using `u.avatar.url.to_path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically call methods on any object in Ruby by using [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send) or `#public_send`:

```
@image_name = 'attachment'; 
@user = User.find(1) puts
@user.send(@image_name).url
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing `eval("@user.#{@image_name}")` which did pretty much what a dot syntax would have done but with variable.

Comment: Don't. Use send instead. Eval is slow and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. `eval` was my last resort. :)